# Overriding and extending trait methods in Pharo

Tags: oop, traits, pharo

Is it possible to extend trait methods by overriding them and calling super?
For example:

```
TMyTrait >> foo
    "do something"

MyClassThatUsesTrait >> foo
    super foo.
    "do something else"
```

Answer (score 2):

Answered on Discord by Cyril Ferlicot:

We can override methods, but traits are here to compose stuff. Not really to specialize stuff.

That being said, there is a workaround that is based on Trait aliases (See Pharo-Wiki: https://github.com/pharo-open-documentation/pharo-wiki/blob/master/General/Traits.md#alias-some-methods-received-from-the-trait)

```
TMyTrait >> foo
    "do something"

Object subclass: #MyClassThatUsesTrait
    uses: TMyTrait @ { #basicFoo -> #foo }
    ...

MyClassThatUsesTrait >> foo
    self basicFoo.
    "do something else"
```

Comment: yes , but this is no a "workaround", is the preview way you should do it ;)